# Not sure how to read lsattr output, where can the legend be found?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, files

When I run the `lsattr` command, I get the following output:

```
root@swarm-stg-01:/etc# lsattr timezone
--------------e--- timezone
```

But I don't understand how to read he output and `man command` doesn't contain this legend.

So what does the "e" mean and what's the significance of the position of the "e" char?

Answer (score 2):

From the `lsattr` man page

> See [`chattr(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html) for a description of the attributes and what they mean.

*... The 'e' attribute indicates that the file is using extents for
       mapping the blocks on disk.  It may not be removed using chattr(1). ...*

Comment: To be fair that’s only half an answer, but I don’t have a quick explanation on what that implies and means

Comment: These days it means very little. But a filesystem upgraded from ext3 to ext4 might have a mix of files which use extents and those created prior to the upgrade which did not.